# How to solve FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Invalid URL react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I couldn't find an answer For Web V9, all I'm trying to do is to delete an image from Firebase-Storage using the URL not the image name as demonstrated in their Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files)

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: ".....",
  databaseURL: ".....",
  projectId: ".......",
  storageBucket: "......",
  messagingSenderId: ".......",
  appId: ".......",
  measurementId: "......"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const database = getDatabase(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app)
export const auth = getAuth()
```

So this is the code that I have tried

```
import { firestore, storage, database } from "../../firebase"
import { deleteObject, ref } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "./firebase";

const SingleApplication = () => {

function delete(){

const ImgUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/......appspot.com/o/Application-Imeges%2F09........"

const dImgRef = ref(storage, ImgUrl) //ImgUrl is a firebase sotrage url

deleteObject(dImgRef).then(() =>{
        console.log("deleted")
        
      })
}

return (
        <div className='Main'>
          </div>
    )
  }
    
    export default SingleApplication
```

**and the error was:**

`Firebase Storage: Invalid URL 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/......appspot.com/o/Application-Imeges%2F09F501.......'`

I'm using react JSX

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can see where is `storage` coming from and is initialized? Also there isn't any `refFromURL` in Firebase modular SDK.

Comment: the Question was edited, actually it is there `import {  refFromURL } from 'firebase/database'`

Comment: Can you also include your `import` statement in this file and also try logging `ImgUrl` once and share the output?

Comment: i couldnt understand your point here the image url is refering to storage image url looks like this `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/....../o/Application-Imeges%2F49106BEA-.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give permission to delete the file on firebase storage rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /folder1/{image} {
      allow read: if true
      ...
      allow delete: if true
    }
  }
}
```

then

```
import { deleteObject, ref } from "firebase/storage"

const pathImage = "folder1/image.jpg" // your path
const reference = ref(storage, pathImage)
deleteObject(reference).then().catch()
```

Comment: if you mean the rules it is true but all i got is `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function. (In 'db._checkNotDeleted('ref')', 'db._checkNotDeleted' is undefined)`

Comment: I don't have the name of the image it is a unique String random string i only have the URL wich is looks like this `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/....../o/Application-Imeges%2F49106BEA-.....` i have tried your answer

Comment: Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Invalid URL 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:4

Comment: the path of the image is in the URL too. It is the string right after "o/", excluding http params (like "?alt=media&token=<token>").

Comment: In your case: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/....../o/Application-Imeges%2F49106BEA-.....`

the path is: `Application-Imeges/49106BEA-.....`

considering that "%2F" = "/"

Comment: actually your answer is right so i will accept it + my code doesn't seems to have a problem so i was given this error because the url was not found that's why, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour